# Cannot import Python module in same package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I have a Python 3.9.2 project with the following directory structure:

```
lib/
├─ mod1.py
├─ mod2.py
├─ __init__.py
main.py
```

In `/main.py`, I have `from lib import mod1`. In `/lib/mod1.py`, I have `import mod2`. When I run `/main.py`, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib import mod1
  File "/lib/init.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mod2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod2'
```

Why is this happening? When I change the code in `/lib/mod1.py` to say `from lib import mod2`, the code works fine, but I don't understand why that fixes it. Shouldn't I be able to import `/lib/mod2.py` the way I originally tried, since both `mod1.py` and `mod2.py` are in the same directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/lib/mod1.py`, you probably want to do:

```py
# relative import - entire module
from . import mod2

# relative import - specific piece
from .mod2 import foo
```

or

```py
# absolute import - entire module
from lib import mod2

# absolute import - specific piece
from lib.mod2 import foo
```

The correct way to import things is really tricky in Python because it depends on where you run the script from.

- If you run the code from the root directory, `import mod2` causes problems, but
- If you were to run `/lib/mod1.py` (say it were run-able) from inside `lib`, then `import mod2` would be correct and the alternatives above would cause errors.

Comment: It worked for me when I used `from . import mod2`, but not with `import .mod2`. If I wanted to ensure that the script was run-able, would I have to use `if __name__ == "__main__"` to check whether it was being run as an independent script?

Comment: Ah, that was a syntax error. Fixed! You don't need `if __name__ == "__main__"` to make a script run-able, but its a good practice. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Can using `if __name__ == "__main__"` be used to check whether to run `import mod2` (as you said at the bottom of your post, this might cause an error depending on how the script is run)?